# Java RMI - Server and Client Running on Different Machines Throws ConnectException: Operation timed out

Tags: java, rmi

I'm writing a Java RMI program that has the server and clients running on different machines.

The problem happens when I call remote methods between the server and clients. These remote methods work well when the server and clients are all running within the same machine, but they don't work by taking extremely long time to cause operation timed out error when the server and clients are working on different machines.

Server side code:

```
public class ServerImplementation extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Server {

    public static void init() {
        System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "172.2x.xx.xx");
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        registry.rebind("Server", new ServerImplementation());
        ...
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public void serverSideMethod() throws RemoteException {
        ...
        someClientObject.clientSideMethod();
    }
}
```

Client side code:

```
public class ClientImplementation extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Client {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("172.2x.xx.xx", 1099);
        Server server = (Server) registry.lookup("Server");
        ...
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public void clientSideMethod() throws RemoteException { ... }
}
```

Error stack trace from the server side:

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:209)
    ...
    at some_package.ServerImplementation.serverSideMethod(ServerImplementation.java:89)
```

I've disabled the firewall on all machines. The address 172.2x.xx.xx is my IP address. Thanks!

Comment: @ZINEMahmoud Why would you have HTTPS proxy settings for an RMI,application?

Comment: You need to set `java.rmi.server.hostname` at the client to its public IP address, as well as doing that at the server. You can see that the server is trying to contact 127.0.0.1, not the client's IP address.

Comment: @ZINEMahmoud I'd just tried by placing them after the line System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "172.2x.xx.xx") at the server side's code, but they did not work :( I also had replaced "PortNumber" with "1099" and "80" but did not work.

Comment: @JayM. Don't waste your time. HTTPS has nothing to do with RMI.

Comment: @user207421 I've just tried yours and it worked!!! Thank you so much for the help! :)